# Link2SD not working completely

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, internal-storage, insufficient-memory, link2sd

My Link2SD doesn't seem to be fully working. I noticed this when updating the Facebook application. Google Play prompted me of insufficient storage. I first uninstalled some apps but I got curious so I checked Link2SD's storage info, I got this:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

As you can see, the internal storage only has mere 70mb left. What's peculiar is, these are the only apps I have NOT linked:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I tried moving one linked app (Amazing Alex) to the sd card (normal Android way) and sure enough, the free space on my internal storage got bigger by about an additional 20mb-ish.

Why is this happening? Why isn't Link2SD moving the data to my sdext2? How do I solve it?

Comment: Did you check with the [Link2SD FAQ](http://www.link2sd.info/faq)? It describes some similar issues, though not exactly what you wrote. But maybe while reading all the questions there, you encounter something deeper which could explain your issue -- as you know best what steps you took, it might be more obvious to you than to others.

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered this problem with link2sd multiple times already. You can try to recreate your mount script via link2sd, reboot and then relink all your application files, lib files, and dalvik-cache.. hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't solve it.

Comment: then my last resort to that problem was to reflash your rom.. sorry dude.. i know it hurts.. but have a backup just in case..

Answer (score 2):

Many people have that kind of problem and I have the same one. moving apps to SD card just delays a bit the problem because something else fills up the internal storage. I finally figured out and it works great. I have a Galaxy Tab 7 but many android devices will experience that. There are 2 important folders. The one called /data is actually not really just data but it is where Android install the application apk and some of the data related to it. If you force the apk to install on SD card, it will still use some of the /data space (small amount) for some data.

the problem I discovered is in /data/tombstone, you will find 10 files named tombstone_0#. These are debugging info collected by android. These files build up over time. You don't need that for a normal user. Delete all of them. These 4 files were using 1.4GB of my 1.89GB internal tablet storage.

To do so, you will need to root your device. Yes, you must. And it won't explode don't worry, I've done it and many others too! Then get a program like "Root Explorer" to browse and delete the junk. It will request and be granted root privilege if you rooted your device before and you will be able to do whatever you want.

To root your device, just google "root android my device model" and you should find quickly how to root your device.

This problem is a design flaw. When there is a low internal storage, Android should start a background task to clean up that junk.

Answer (score 1):

Often the system recreates some of the files that were previously linked to sdext2.  This often happens with libraries, but can affect other components (apk, dex) as well.

For libraries, Link2SD has a “Relink all library files” command in its menu.  There's also an option to do this each time the system boots.

You can also look at your linked apps and see which components are still linked (symbolized with a little arrow -> in the app list) and manually relink components if necessary.